# JFrame blocked after creating socket connection

Tags: java, swing, sockets

so i've been trying to learn about sockets, and was trying to create a simple chat app where  i have 2 `JFrames`  and each connects to socket,  the problem is that  every time i run the `JFrames`
the frames start correctly, but when  i click on the  `connect_button` the socket starts connection but  doesn't let me continue  with the operations,  everything is blocked from this point forward, i've been realy trying to understand but im stuck here, any thoughts ?

> 1. i think  my problem is that  the sockets  should  go  in their own Threads, but i've seen other  solutions and  seen that  they don't  implement  Threads,  or at least in the code that  they show.
> 2. maybe  my socket connection  is  implemented  incorrectly.

¿Is it wrong to use  `PrintStream` if so, is it still posible to use this class to proceed with this excercise  and  which  `Stream` class should i use ?  Taking  into count that i understand that  bufferedStreams are the way to go if you want  efficiency

Comment: "*maybe my socket connection is implemented incorrectly*" > It's always a good idea to separate these concerns. Try a command-line program to test your socket code. Once that's working, add a GUI.

Comment: Don't post your whole application but a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Swing is not thread safe.  That is, all UI events occur within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, including paint events.

Anything that blocks this thread will prevent the EDT from processing new events and essentially make your application look like it's hung.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details...

The call to `initServerConnector` in the `actionPerformed` method of the `Messenger_Controller` class is creating a new `Conector` which is creating a `ServerSocket` and calling `accept` on it, which is a blocking method.  This is preventing the EDT from processing new events until it returns.

Instead, you should be using either a `SwingWorker` or `Thread` to manage the `Socket` connections and communications.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

Swing components should also not be updated from outside the context of the EDT.  This means if you need to make changes to the UI while processing the socket comms, you will need to sync those updates back to the UI.

If you're using a `SwingWorker`, you can use the `publish`/`process` methods or you will need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, both approaches will sync the calls back to the EDT where you can makes changes safely...

Answer (score 0):

You create your socket and handle network traffic in the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) because you do this in an `ActionListener`. This is the same thread that is used to paint the GUI of your application and handle interactions with the user.

You should not do lengthy task in the EDT but start a new thread for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you retain your GUI thread to make socket communication it is for sure, this will block your thread(UI).

What is required is some async or non blocking way to make socket communication, which does not block your GUI thread.

Keep your GUI thread separate and runs on its own and make socket connection through creating `FutureTask` or `ForkJoinTask` or `Thread` or non blocking socket communication  which updates once you received communication message.

[Example to create non blocking socket](http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.in/2011/05/creating-non-blocking-client-and-server.html)